# Print calculation result of textfield value as you type

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have 2 textboxes which accepts the price and the discount. As I enter values in to these textboxes I need to calculate the price after discount and print it.

However, the price after discount doesn't get displayed. Can someone help me please.

```
 <h1> Price after discount is  {{price/discount * 100}} % </h1>

 <input type="number" name" class="form-control" aria-label="price " pattern="[0-9]"
               [disabled]="true" name="price "  formControlName="price "/>

 <input type="number" name" class="form-control" aria-label="discount " pattern="[0-9]"
               [disabled]="true" name="discount "  formControlName="discount "/>
```

Comment: Check [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kq7wf2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) possible solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your combining data binding with reactive forms. The H1 is binding to two public properties on the component called price and discount respectively.

The inputs are using two formControl instances, one called price, the other called discount.  Presumably, somewhere above the H1 you have an outer level element like a div with a [formGroup]="myFormGroup" binding.  myFormGroup would also be a property of the component (and would have a price control and a discount control).

Anyway, to get it working, either:

1. Define a public read-only property for price, and another one called discount, which get their values from the formGroup:

```js
public get price(): number {
  return this.myFormGroup.controls.price.value; 
}

public get discount(): number {
  return this.myFormGroup.controls.discount.value;
}
```

2. Define read/write public properties for price and discount, and write to them as the form control values change:

```js
public price: number;
public discount: number;
private priceChangedSubsription: Subscription;
private discountChangedSubscription: Subscription;

public myFormGroup: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
  price: new FormControl(0),
  discount: newFormControl(0),
});

// Remember to implement NgOnDestroy, and unsubscibe from this observable there 
this.priceChangedSubscription = this.myFormGroup.controls.price.valueChange.subscribe(val => {
  this.price = val;
});

// Do the same for discount changes
```

Comment: FunkMonkey, you can write directly: `{{+myFormGroup.value.price*(100-myFormGroup.value.discount)/100}}`, even use number pipe `{{(+myFormGroup.value.price*(100-myFormGroup.value.discount)/100)|number:'1.2-2'}}`

Comment: Eliseo, you're absolutely correct.  You can reach into the form directly from the template.